# Is it possible to connect to SSH via not standard ports via a router I do not control?

Tags: ssh

I live in an apartment complex with about 20 units. I have been given a Wi-Fi username and password but no access to the router. Which is fine, I understand why.

However, I have Windows 10 with Bitvise SSH server installed. I am trying to figure out a way to connect to it via the public IP, without having to access the router to allow port `8022`, `22`, or whatever I choose.

It’s a basic Xfinity router. I know port `80` is allowed, but i tried to set my SSH server to that and it fails to connect.

Comment: First, I am sorry to say that what you are describing might not be possible. That said, the [main edits I made to your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1443127/revisions) concern tone and such… All those “Haha…” things really are not what this site is about. This is not a forum or chatroom, but rather a unique question and answer site.

Comment: Most likely you're behind NAT and IPv6 is out of the question. If there was a machine that you could log into via SSH both from your Windows and from anywhere else, then it could act as a relay. E.g. [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1439951/432690) asks for IPv6 but what the user did with IPv4 is exactly what I'm talking about. Do you have SSH access to any host with a public IP that could act as a relay then?

Comment: so laughter and happiness is not welcome on this site? note taken. i will keep posts emotionless

I do not have access to another outside server... sadly. Yes, the router is for sure a NATed router. I just wish i could piggyback on another port that is allowed in such as port 80. I did read that other article you pointed out. that was what initiated me to post here. 

thnaks

Comment: Granted i could use hamachi to ssh that way, but then thats kind of pointless since i could just mapp a drive at that point, and most university or public libraries will not allow users to install software, hence i would use a USB ssh client, but this is looking kind of like a shot in the dark for me..

Comment: @MattThomas “so laughter and happiness is not welcome on this site?” No, that is not true at all. But the reality is your overall formatting, lack of basic grammar and numerous spelling issues on top of the “Haha…” makes your post sound like something from a random BBS; meaning it doesn’t sound intelligent and it doesn’t make people take you seriously. Anyway, you have an answer now. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You cant "connect to ssh via non standard ports via a router you dont control" unless the router is configured to forward a non-standard port on TCP to your IP address which is unlikely.

There are (at least) 2 common workarrounds -

1. Use a reverse ssh tunnel. (I cant comment on whether you can use bitwise ssh for this)
2. Use VPNs.

One way to do this would.be to set up something like an OpenVPN server on an EC2 instance or other virtual machine (VM) Connect the computer behind nat to it as an openvpn client.  You can then either ssh to the VM and then ssh across the VPN to your PC over SSH or set up a second VPN from the external device you want to connect to to the same VPN, along with appropriate routing and then you can access any services on your PC via the VPN.

A simpler alternative would be to find a VPN provider that will issue you a static IP. In this way you just need the VPN client to connect to the ISP and then you can access your machine via that external IP. Do a google/ddg search for "vpn static IP" for providers of this service. The closer to you the VPN is the better (because if you get an IP on the other side of the world the latency can make ssh feel very slow)